# VLOOKUP ID# Across Sheet in Workbook

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to lookup the Value in Sheet 1, cell A5, against Sheet 2, column A, and return the corresponding Value in Sheet 2 Column D. The Formula I am using is as such:

```
=VLOOKUP(A5,sheet2!A:D,4,FALSE)
```

However, I get an #N/A error - What step am I missing here?

Sheet  1:

[image]

Sheet 2, Same Workbook:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the second worksheet has the numbers stored as strings. If you're first sheet doesn't also have them as strings, that could be causing the error

Try this:

`=VLOOKUP(A5&"", Sheet2!A:D,4,FALSE)`

By appending a nullstring to A5 it makes it become a string and should allow it to match with the second sheet

Comment: I didn't know you could translate a cell to string variable like that!! Thanks for teaching me :)!

Comment: @Wizhi if you need to go the other way something i've seen is to go `--A5` to make it into a number

Comment: Huge thanks :), always fun to learn new tricks :P. Much appreciated!!